# Repeating an input if the output is false

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to make a "guess the number" game in python where i choose the minimum and maximum number and i want it to repeat the question if the number i chose is lower or higher, how can i do that?

here's my code:

```
import random
import time

print("Welcome to the guessing game!")

time.sleep(1)

print("Choose your minumum number")

minnum=input("Min: ")

print(" ")

print("Choose your maximum number")

maxnum=input("Max: ")

print(" ")

print("Enter your number")

num = input("Number: ")

print(" ")

q = random.randint(int(minnum), int(maxnum))

def game():
    if int(num) < q:
        print("The number is higher")

    if int(num) > q:
        print("The number is lower")

    if int(num) == q:
        print("Congratulations! you won!")
        break
game()
print(" ")
print(" ")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Comment: You can't have a `break` statement outside of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variation performs additional validation if you'd like that:

```
from random import randint


def request_user_input(query):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(query))
        except ValueError:
            continue

def run_game(target):
    while True:
        guess = request_user_input('Enter your number: ')
        if guess < target:
            print('The number is higher')
        elif guess > target:
            print('The number is lower')
        else:
            print('Congratulations! You won!')
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    min = request_user_input('Min: ')
    max = request_user_input('Max: ')
    if max < min:
        raise ValueError('The maximum value cannot be smaller than the minimum')

    run_game(target=randint(min, max + 1))
```

**Example Run**

```
Min: a
Min: 10
Max: 20
Enter your number: 5
The number is higher
Enter your number: 25
The number is lower
Enter your number: 15
The number is higher
Enter your number: 18
The number is higher
Enter your number: 20
The number is lower
Enter your number: 19
Congratulations! You won!
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the input inside the game() and make it a loop like so:

```
def game():
    while True:
        print("Enter your number")

        num = input("Number: ")

        if int(num) < q:
            print("The number is higher")

        if int(num) > q:
            print("The number is lower")

        if int(num) == q:
            print("Congratulations! you won!")
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `while` loop to keep continuing if the user has inputted a wrong guess and if correct the loop will exit by `break`:

```
import random
import time

print("Welcome to the guessing game!")
time.sleep(1)
print("Choose your minumum number")
minnum=input("Min: ")
print(" ")
print("Choose your maximum number")
maxnum=input("Max: ")
print(" ")
q = random.randint(int(minnum), int(maxnum))

def game():
  while True: #while loop for looping continuously until correct input
      print("Enter your number")
      num = input("Number: ")
      print(" ")

      if int(num) < q:
          print("The number is higher")

      if int(num) > q:
          print("The number is lower")

      if int(num) == q: #if answer correct stop looping 
          print("Congratulations! you won!")
          break

game()
print(" ")
print(" ")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the guessing game!
Choose your minumum number
Min: 1

Choose your maximum number
Max: 5

Enter your number
Number: 3

The number is lower
Enter your number
Number: 4

The number is lower
Enter your number
Number: 5

The number is lower
Enter your number
Number: 2

Congratulations! you won!
```